# Arduino-like boards with other microcontrollers

Tags: avr

Are there any *Arduino-like* board designs that are ***NOT*** using an AVR chip, but perhaps a chip like the Z80 or the 6502?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "Arduino-like"? Pin layout, IDE, etc. E.g. TI launchpad can be programmed using Energia which is an Arduino-like IDE and library based on Wiring but doesn't have the same pin layout.

Comment: What meaning do you put in *Arduino-like* ?  Support for Arduino development environment?

Comment: If you want to use PICs, maybe [chipKit](http://www.digilentinc.com/Products/Catalog.cfm?NavPath=2,892&Cat=18&CFID=7602134&CFTOKEN=d596cdbdb10c35f8-1840D2BC-5056-0201-02DC9FE540EF6E8F) is worth a look.

Comment: Today is your lucky day: http://hackaday.com/2015/02/17/non-arduino-powered-by-a-piece-of-computing-history/

Comment: Z80 and 6502 are CPUs (**not** MCUs) of another time; I am not even sure you can find some to buy now! Why one would create some board around them today?

Comment: [Teensy](https://www.pjrc.com/teensy/teensy31.html) or Arduino Due (both ARM). [TI Launchpad Series](http://www.ti.com/ww/en/launchpad/launchpads-msp430.html). Just to name a few.

Answer (score 1):

You have to define what you mean by "Arduino-like" beyond just not using an AVR.

There's the Arduino Galileo using an Intel chip and supports the Arduino development tools, as well as the Arduino Due which is an Arm-based chip.

There's the Netduino which uses ARM chips (STMicro's) and is pin compatible with Arduino shields, but I don't know what the development framework is (other than it being in .NET), though this doesn't necessarily say much because not even all Arduino boards have the same pin compatibility (Nano boards are much smaller, LilyPad Arduinos which are round and semi-flexible, etc.)

Then there are related boards, but don't support the Arduino environment or any pin compatibility (TI Launchpad springs immediately to mind, but pretty much every manufacturer has some sort of demo board or development board for their MCU's).

There's a huge list of Arduino-like boards [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Arduino_boards_and_compatible_systems) (split into levels of compatibility, includes the official Arduino boards).

Comment: By Arduino-Like I mean a small board with the same or very similar physical dimensions of an Arduino Uno and a very similar feature set related to Analog and Digital I/O, memory, video, etc.

Comment: Define 'very similar'? And what video features does an Arduino have??